# Variant SKU not accessible in Twig

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am unable to access a variants sku.

```
{% set product = craft.products.id(productId).with('productImages').one() %}
{% set defaultVariant = product.defaultVariant %}
{% set variants = craft.variants().productID(product.id) %}    
{% set purchasable = purchasableId ?? defaultVariant.id %}
{% set myVariantQuery = craft.variants.id(purchasable) ?? '' %}
{% set selectedVariant = myVariantQuery.one() %}
```

This is the set up and from what I can see in the docs I should be able now do the following in Twig:

```
{{ selectedVariant.sku }}
```

But this does not work.

This is what is available:

```
{
  "productId": "183",
  "isDefault": "0",
  "price": "4.9500",
  "sortOrder": "2",
  "width": null,
  "height": null,
  "length": null,
  "weight": null,
  "stock": "0",
  "hasUnlimitedStock": "0",
  "minQty": null,
  "maxQty": null,
  "deletedWithProduct": false,
  "id": 185,
  "tempId": null,
  "draftId": null,
  "revisionId": null,
  "uid": "5dd47b96-2635-4a85-bdf9-e2850efe4f71",
  "siteSettingsId": 185,
  "fieldLayoutId": 39,
  "structureId": null,
  "contentId": 176,
  "enabled": true,
  "archived": false,
  "siteId": 1,
  "title": "250g",
  "slug": null,
  "uri": null,
  "dateCreated": {
    "date": "2021-03-01 07:14:11.000000",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "dateUpdated": {
    "date": "2021-05-28 12:59:47.000000",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "dateDeleted": null,
  "root": null,
  "lft": null,
  "rgt": null,
  "level": null,
  "searchScore": null,
  "trashed": false,
  "awaitingFieldValues": false,
  "propagating": false,
  "propagateAll": false,
  "newSiteIds": [],
  "resaving": false,
  "duplicateOf": null,
  "previewing": false,
  "hardDelete": false
}
```

The product has a SKU in admin:

[image]

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really follow what you're trying to do with that twig, to be honest (I think you've got a bit lost in the Commerce Product/variant/purchasabale language, which is unfortunately easy to do!)....

...But if you're just wanting to display the SKU of a product, then try this:

Assuming a valid `productId`....

For a product without variants:

```
{% set product = craft.products.id(productId).one() %}
{% set variant = product.defaultVariant %}
{{ variant.sku }}
```

For a product with variants:

```
{% set product = craft.products.id(productId).one() %}
{% set variants = product.variants %}
{% for variant in variants %}
   {{ variant.sku }}
{% endfor %}
```

...that should do it.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy! I could not figure this out. Based on your answer I was able to switch this line:

`{% set variants = craft.variants().productID(product.id) %} `

For:


`{% set variants = product.variants %}`


And this then allowed me to access `{{ variant.sku }}`